# windows 10 docker kitematic setup error

Tags: docker, installation, kitematic

Somebody can help me install the docker kitematic, [error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkCWC.png)

Detailed error messages are in below:

```
 Command failed: C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe -D start default,Docker Machine Version: 0.12.2, build 9371605,Found binary path at C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe,Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox,Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:1824,() Calling .GetVersion,Using API Version 1,() Calling .SetConfigRaw,() Calling .GetMachineName,command=start machine=default,(default) Calling .GetState,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo default
    --machinereadable,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | name="default",(default) DBG | groups="/",(default) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)",(default) DBG | UUID="29670225-f9e7-426f-8abf-00613dd1063c",(default) DBG | CfgFile="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\default.vbox",(default) DBG | SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Snapshots",(default) DBG | LogFldr="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Logs",(default) DBG | hardwareuuid="29670225-f9e7-426f-8abf-00613dd1063c",(default) DBG | memory=2048,(default) DBG | pagefusion="off",(default) DBG | vram=8,(default) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100,(default) DBG | hpet="on",(default) DBG | chipset="piix3",(default) DBG | firmware="BIOS",(default) DBG | cpus=1,(default) DBG | pae="on",(default) DBG | longmode="on",(default) DBG | triplefaultreset="off",(default) DBG | apic="on",(default) DBG | x2apic="off",(default) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0,(default) DBG | bootmenu="disabled",(default) DBG | boot1="dvd",(default) DBG | boot2="dvd",(default) DBG | boot3="disk",(default) DBG | boot4="none",(default) DBG | acpi="on",(default) DBG | ioapic="on",(default) DBG | biosapic="apic",(default) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0,(default) DBG | rtcuseutc="on",(default) DBG | hwvirtex="on",(default) DBG | nestedpaging="on",(default) DBG | largepages="on",(default) DBG | vtxvpid="on",(default) DBG | vtxux="on",(default) DBG | paravirtprovider="default",(default) DBG | effparavirtprovider="kvm",(default) DBG | VMState="poweroff",(default) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2017-09-30T07:45:34.000000000",(default) DBG | monitorcount=1,(default) DBG | accelerate3d="off",(default) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off",(default) DBG | teleporterenabled="off",(default) DBG | teleporterport=0,(default) DBG | teleporteraddress="",(default) DBG | teleporterpassword="",(default) DBG | tracing-enabled="off",(default) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off",(default) DBG | tracing-config="",(default) DBG | autostart-enabled="off",(default) DBG | autostart-delay=0,(default) DBG | defaultfrontend="",(default) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA",(default) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0",(default) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on",(default) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="1a30a43c-7461-4c1e-a4a3-bc17aef25bf2",(default) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="c57b3f2f-6252-4971-a404-f4c431398c44",(default) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none",(default) Calling .Start,(default) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none",(default) DBG | natnet1="nat",(default) DBG | macaddress1="08002763934E",(default) DBG | cableconnected1="on",(default) DBG | nic1="nat",(default) DBG | nictype1="82540EM",(default) DBG | nicspeed1="0",(default) DBG | mtu="0",(default) DBG | sockSnd="64",(default) DBG | sockRcv="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64",(default) DBG | nic2="none",(default) DBG | nic3="none",(default) DBG | nic4="none",(default) DBG | nic5="none",(default) DBG | nic6="none",(default) DBG | nic7="none",(default) DBG | nic8="none",(default) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse",(default) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd",(default) DBG | uart1="off",(default) DBG | uart2="off",(default) DBG | uart3="off",(default) DBG | uart4="off",(default) DBG | lpt1="off",(default) DBG | lpt2="off",(default) DBG | audio="dsound",(default) DBG | clipboard="disabled",(default) DBG | draganddrop="disabled",(default) DBG | vrde="off",(default) DBG | usb="off",(default) DBG | ehci="off",(default) DBG | xhci="off",(default) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="c/Users",(default) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\c:\Users",(default) DBG | vcpenabled="off",(default) DBG | vcpscreens=0,(default) DBG | vcpfile="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.webm",(default) DBG | vcpwidth=1024,(default) DBG | vcpheight=768,(default) DBG | vcprate=512,(default) DBG | vcpfps=25,(default) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe showvminfo default
    --machinereadable,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | name="default",(default) DBG | groups="/",(default) DBG | ostype="Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (64-bit)",(default) DBG | UUID="29670225-f9e7-426f-8abf-00613dd1063c",(default) DBG | CfgFile="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\default.vbox",(default) DBG | SnapFldr="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Snapshots",(default) DBG | LogFldr="C:\\Users\\YJW\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\default\\default\\Logs",(default) DBG | hardwareuuid="29670225-f9e7-426f-8abf-00613dd1063c",(default) DBG | memory=2048,(default) DBG | pagefusion="off",(default) DBG | vram=8,(default) DBG | cpuexecutioncap=100,(default) DBG | hpet="on",(default) DBG | chipset="piix3",(default) DBG | firmware="BIOS",(default) DBG | cpus=1,(default) DBG | pae="on",(default) DBG | longmode="on",(default) DBG | triplefaultreset="off",(default) DBG | apic="on",(default) DBG | x2apic="off",(default) DBG | cpuid-portability-level=0,(default) DBG | bootmenu="disabled",(default) DBG | boot1="dvd",(default) DBG | boot2="dvd",(default) DBG | boot3="disk",(default) DBG | boot4="none",(default) DBG | acpi="on",(default) DBG | ioapic="on",(default) DBG | biosapic="apic",(default) DBG | biossystemtimeoffset=0,(default) DBG | rtcuseutc="on",(default) DBG | hwvirtex="on",(default) DBG | nestedpaging="on",(default) DBG | largepages="on",(default) DBG | vtxvpid="on",(default) DBG | vtxux="on",(default) DBG | paravirtprovider="default",(default) DBG | effparavirtprovider="kvm",(default) DBG | VMState="poweroff",(default) DBG | VMStateChangeTime="2017-09-30T07:45:34.000000000",(default) DBG | monitorcount=1,(default) DBG | accelerate3d="off",(default) DBG | accelerate2dvideo="off",(default) DBG | teleporterenabled="off",(default) DBG | teleporterport=0,(default) DBG | teleporteraddress="",(default) DBG | teleporterpassword="",(default) DBG | tracing-enabled="off",(default) DBG | tracing-allow-vm-access="off",(default) DBG | tracing-config="",(default) DBG | autostart-enabled="off",(default) DBG | autostart-delay=0,(default) DBG | defaultfrontend="",(default) DBG | storagecontrollername0="SATA",(default) DBG | storagecontrollertype0="IntelAhci",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerinstance0="0",(default) DBG | storagecontrollermaxportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerportcount0="30",(default) DBG | storagecontrollerbootable0="on",(default) DBG | "SATA-0-0"="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-0-0"="1a30a43c-7461-4c1e-a4a3-bc17aef25bf2",(default) DBG | "SATA-tempeject"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-IsEjected"="off",(default) DBG | "SATA-1-0"="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\disk.vmdk",(default) DBG | "SATA-ImageUUID-1-0"="c57b3f2f-6252-4971-a404-f4c431398c44",(default) DBG | "SATA-2-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-3-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-4-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-5-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-6-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-7-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-8-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-9-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-10-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-11-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-12-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-13-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-14-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-15-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-16-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-17-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-18-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-19-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-20-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-21-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-22-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-23-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-24-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-25-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-26-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-27-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-28-0"="none",(default) DBG | "SATA-29-0"="none",(default) DBG | natnet1="nat",(default) DBG | macaddress1="08002763934E",(default) DBG | cableconnected1="on",(default) DBG | nic1="nat",(default) DBG | nictype1="82540EM",(default) DBG | nicspeed1="0",(default) DBG | mtu="0",(default) DBG | sockSnd="64",(default) DBG | sockRcv="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndSnd="64",(default) DBG | tcpWndRcv="64",(default) DBG | nic2="none",(default) DBG | nic3="none",(default) DBG | nic4="none",(default) DBG | nic5="none",(default) DBG | nic6="none",(default) DBG | nic7="none",(default) DBG | nic8="none",(default) DBG | hidpointing="ps2mouse",(default) DBG | hidkeyboard="ps2kbd",(default) DBG | uart1="off",(default) DBG | uart2="off",(default) DBG | uart3="off",(default) DBG | uart4="off",(default) DBG | lpt1="off",(default) DBG | lpt2="off",(default) DBG | audio="dsound",(default) DBG | clipboard="disabled",(default) DBG | draganddrop="disabled",(default) DBG | vrde="off",(default) DBG | usb="off",(default) DBG | ehci="off",(default) DBG | xhci="off",(default) DBG | SharedFolderNameMachineMapping1="c/Users",(default) DBG | SharedFolderPathMachineMapping1="\\?\c:\Users",(default) DBG | vcpenabled="off",(default) DBG | vcpscreens=0,(default) DBG | vcpfile="C:\Users\YJW\.docker\machine\machines\default\default\default.webm",(default) DBG | vcpwidth=1024,(default) DBG | vcpheight=768,(default) DBG | vcprate=512,(default) DBG | vcpfps=25,(default) DBG | GuestMemoryBalloon=0,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | Searching for hostonly interface for IPv4:
    192.168.99.1 and Mask: ffffff00,(default) DBG | Not found,(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe hostonlyif create,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | 0%...,(default) DBG | Progress state: E_FAIL,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find Host Interface Networking driver! Please reinstall,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface,(default) DBG | VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | COMMAND: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe list hostonlyifs,(default) DBG | STDOUT:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },(default) DBG | STDERR:,(default) DBG | {,(default) DBG | },Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue,
```

Comment: Could you modify the post and tell us when the error occurs and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message shows, It seems that you have an old version of virtualbox:

> ...
>
> This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it
>   and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this
>   issue

Try uninstalling virtualbox, and install the latest version from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Kitematic installation in windows 10 is very easy to do. I have found the proper documentation with the step by the step installation process and I succeeded to install it. Go through with this link to understand more about [Docker Kitematic installation in Windows 10](https://www.javaisocean.com/2019/10/docker-kitematic-installation.html)

**Key points:**

1. Make sure you have made required Hyper-v, Virtualization changes in BIOS settings.
2. Make sure your Docker installed properly.

**Problem:** As per my understanding, your docker installation directory is not placed with the proper path to place Kitematic extracted files. Default paths of Docker & Kitematic installation directories are below,

**Docker:** C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker

**Kitematic:** C:\Program Files\Docker\Kitematic

**Note:** If you have already installed VirtualBox, it may cause problems to Docker containerization.

Comment: If the docker is working fine, no need to do any changes in BIOS settings.