# Kitematic gets error when connecting to Docker Hub “self signed certificate in certificate chain”

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, kitematic

I am setting up Docker environment on Windows 10. Now Docker desktop is up and running and I could use docker commands as well. I tried to click Kitematic on Docker Desktop menu and downloaded Kitematic Windows from there. Unzipped and clicked exe to run. When it started asked immediately my docker account for docker hub and I typed my login info. I could not logged in.

Then there is an error appeared on login form: "self signed certificate in certificate chain". I can login my account from https://hub.docker.com/, so I know my credentials are correct.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I have a similar - though subtly different - issue.  I don't get the "self-signed cert" message.  Instead, my login to the Docker Hub just hangs with an infinite turning circle.  No time-outs or visible error messages (I couldn't find any log-files in which errors might be reported either).

Comment: Check my answer posted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500920/windows-10-docker-kitematic-setup-error it may help you.